# How do I exit a Qt script if a condition is met?

Tags: c++, qt, quit, qtscript

I want to do something like

```
if(x == 0){
quit() ; 
}
```

is there a way to do this in a Qt Script?

Comment: call `QCoreApplication::exit`

Comment: I think that exits a Qt application not a script

Comment: what do you mean by "exit"? Leave the function? Try with return;

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your code inside a function like this:

```
function main(){
   // the code before
   if(x == 0){
      return;
   }
   // the code if condition not met
}
```

So you can exit javascript the code using the return statement. Make sure the main function is  the only one called in your action (so it really quits from JS).